# Angular RxJS: Subject<void>.asObservable() returns undefined

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've created an `Subject` in order to populate some event clicks:

```
<button type="search" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="search()">
    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cercar
</button>
```

My component is:

```
private searchClickSubject:Subject<void>;
private searchClick$:Observable<void>;

constructor() {
    this.searchClickSubject = new Subject<void>();
    this.searchClick$ = this.searchClickSubject.asObservable();   <<<1>>>
}

private search(): void {
    this.searchClickSubject.next();
}
```

Nevertheless, after `<<<1>>>`, `this.searchClick$ = this.searchClickSubject.asObservable();`, it returns `undefined`.

Any ideas?

Comment: where are you logging `undefined`?

Comment: on `<<<1>>>` (`this.searchClick$ = this.searchClickSubject.asObservable();`). I mean that `this.searchClickSubject.asObservable()` returns `undefined`

Comment: Use `{}` instead of `void`, and `next({})`?

Comment: @Mic. It keeps failing.

Comment: What are your imports?

Comment: Also as a side note, you should probably use `@Output` in your case, instead of rebuilding the `Subject` yourself.